# Issue with renaming a bunch of files in a directory using Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
  import os
    def rename_files():
        file_list = os.listdir(r"G:\Python_Learning\prank")
        print(file_list)
        saved_path =os.getcwd()
        print("Current working directory is "+saved_path)
        os.chdir(r"G:\Python_Learning\prank")
        for file_name in file_list:
            os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
            os.chdir(saved_path)
    rename_files()
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
     1. -Error: -Traceback (most recent call last): -File 
"C:/Python34/rename_files.py", line 11, in <module> -rename_files()
        -File "C:/Python34/rename_files.py", line 9, in rename_files -os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None, b"0123456789")) -TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, [`str.translate` takes only one argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

> str.translate(map) Return a copy of the s where all characters have
>   been mapped through the map which must be a dictionary of Unicode
>   ordinals (integers) to Unicode ordinals, strings or None. Unmapped
>   characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None are deleted.
>
> You can use str.maketrans() to create a translation map from
>   character-to-character mappings in different formats.
>
> Note An even more flexible approach is to create a custom character
>   mapping codec using the codecs module (see encodings.cp1251 for an
>   example).

This works differently from [`str.translate` in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=.translate#str.translate).

If you're just trying to remove characters, you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html):

```
import os
import re

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"G:\Python_Learning\prank")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path =os.getcwd()
    print("Current working directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"G:\Python_Learning\prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name,re.sub("[0-9]","", file_name))
        os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Comment: I get this error now:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\rename_files.py", line 12, in <module>
    rename_files()
  File "C:\Python34\rename_files.py", line 10, in rename_files
    os.rename(file_name,re.sub("[0-9]","", file_name))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '0123456789' -> ''

Comment: Hmmm....I can't replicate the error. `re.sub("[0-9]", "", file_name)` should replace any digit in `file_name` with the empty string. Try printing out `re.sub("[0-9]", "", file_name)` before calling `os.rename` and see what comes out.

Comment: Still the same: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\rename_files.py", line 13, in <module>
    rename_files()
  File "C:\Python34\rename_files.py", line 11, in rename_files
    os.rename(file_name,re.sub("[0-9]","", file_name))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '0123456789' -> ''
>>>

Comment: You can try and replicate it by creating a folder with few files containing numbers in their names.

Comment: Ah, well, if the filenames only consist of digits, then `re("[0-9]", "", file_name)` will dutifully return the empty string. It seems as though Windows doesn't like renaming a file to `""` (which isn't a bad idea). So, you'll have to rename those files to something else.

Comment: Not only digits.. they contains alphabets and digits

Comment: Any string containing non-digit characters will not be transformed to the empty string via `re.sub("[0-9]", "", file_name)`.

Comment: Ok... What i need to do is - if the file name is 12chennai, i need to convert it to chennai

Comment: Testing with Python 3.4.2, `re.sub("[0-9]", "", "12chennai")` returns `'chennai'`. The regex substitution fulfills your requirements as stated.

Comment: wierd, but it does not work when i run the above program

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. There must be something else in your code that you've left out of your question that's causing unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Use **str.strip()**.

```
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"G:\Python_Learning\prank")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path =os.getcwd()
    print("Current working directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"G:\Python_Learning\prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name,file_name.strip("0123456789"))
        os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
file_name.translate(None, "01234567789")
```

With

```
 file_name.strip("01234567789")
```

Answer (score 0):

**os.rename(file_name, file_name.strip("01234567789"))**

Comment: Can you be more descriptive?