# "How to fix" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python-3.x

I am new programming and trying small program in python to "Rename the files" in my folder. When i run the program it displayed all the files in folder but getting an error"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'". i am not getting where i made mistake and what actually code is looking for.

```
import string
import os

def Rename_files():

    Files = os.listdir(r"F:\New folder")
    print(Files)
    os.chdir(r"F:\New folder")
    n = os.getcwd()
    print("Current Working Directory is "+n)
  for var in Files:
       os.rename(Files,Files.translate(None,"_"))
Rename_files()
```

Output is follows:

```
['DSC_1041.JPG', 'DSC_1068.JPG', 'DSC_1139.JPG', 'DSC_1160.JPG',                 
'DSC_1172.JPG', 'DSC_1238.JPG', 'DSC_1244.JPG', 'DSC_1245.JPG']
Current Working Directory is F:\New folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32  
\Second.py", line 14, in <module>
Rename_files()
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32 
\Second.py", line 13, in Rename_files
   os.rename(Files,Files.translate(None,"_"))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You want to rename your files like `ab cd.txt` turns `ab_cd.txt`??

Answer (score 0):

In this loop you are trying to rename list object and not an actual element (file).

```
for var in Files:
   os.rename(Files,Files.translate(None,"_"))
```

What you should do, is to replace `Files` with `var`, which is your list element, like this:

```
for var in Files:
   os.rename(var,var.translate(None,"_"))
```

Comment: Hi Jakub,

I have tried but it throwing error again
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: @SaiSrinivas For two arguments error, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270451/issue-with-renaming-a-bunch-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `for loop` you have to use `var` instead of `Files`. and for renaming files you can use `replace()` instead of `translate()`
Try this:

```
import os
def Rename_files():
    Files = os.listdir(r"E:\New folder")
    print(Files)
    os.chdir(r"E:\New folder")
    n = os.getcwd()
    print("Current Working Directory is " + n)
    for var in Files:
        os.rename(var, var.replace(" ", "_"))
Rename_files()
```